# VSS to TFS 2010 Bindings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I recently converted from VSS to TFS 2010. I used VSSConverter (VS2010) and everything went smooth except the bindings. For some of the solutions (web related mostly) the VSS bindings still exist. I get an error opening the solution and I have to manually rebind to TFS. Once I manually bind to TFs everything is good. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The converter does not go into projects and change bindings for you; it merely "replays" every action you ever did on the VSS database on your Team server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Team Foundation Server Power Tools and the command line "tfpt bind" command. I've never used it but it should convert all of your vss bindings to tfs.